# Why isn't jQuery Validate plug in working with one section of my MVC project?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-validate

I am using jQuery Validate plugin on my MVC web app. In one section of the app, the plugin works perfectly. The fields in this section of the app do not have a [Required] field validator attached to any of the fields in the model.

Below is the code that I am trying to make work with the jQuery Validate plugin. It is not working. I have been troubleshooting this for hours, and I can't see the error where I'm going wrong! I tried removing the [Required] field validator in the model and it didn't fix the issue. I'd appreciate another set of eyes...

My MVC Model:

```
public class LoanApp
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

The HTML with Razor Syntax

```
<form id="applicantPersonalInfo">
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2"})
        <div class="col-md-10">
             @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control"} })
             @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
       </div>
    </div> 
</form>
```

The jQuery Validate:

```
$('#applicantPersonalInfo').validate({
   rules: {
      FirstName: {
          required: true
      }    
   },
   onfocusout: function (element) { $(element).valid(); },
   onkeyup: function (element) { $(element).valid(); }
});
```

I have been comparing the two sections for hours and I can't seem to find the issue with the code in this section. Really appreciate the help. Thanks!

Comment: It would be helpful to see the actual rendered HTML markup instead of the server-side Razor code.  The rendered markup is how the JavaScript sees it.

Comment: Explain "not working" along with your expectations.  Are you getting any JavaScript console errors?  Are you using the Unobtrusive Validation plugin?

Comment: You should also never use the `.valid()` method anywhere inside of the `.validate()` method as it could cause an infinite loop.  Replace `$(element).valid()` with `this.element(element)`